# OfflineAudioContext processing takes increasingly longer in Safari

Tags: safari, garbage-collection, mobile-safari, web-audio-api

I am processing an audio buffer with an OfflineAudioContext with the following node layout:

`[AudioBufferSourceNode] -> [AnalyserNode] -> [OfflineAudioContext]`

This works very good on Chrome (106.0.5249.119) but on Safari 16 (17614.1.25.9.10, 17614) each time I run the analysis takes longer and longer. Both running on macOS.

What's curious is that I must quit Safari to "reset" the processing time.

I guess there's a memory leak?

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong in the JavaScript code that would cause Safari to not garbage collect?

```js
async function processFrequencyData(
  audioBuffer,
  options
) {
  const {
    fps,
    numberOfSamples,
    maxDecibels,
    minDecibels,
    smoothingTimeConstant,
  } = options;

  const frameFrequencies = [];

  const oc = new OfflineAudioContext({
    length: audioBuffer.length,
    sampleRate: audioBuffer.sampleRate,
    numberOfChannels: audioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
  });

  const lengthInMillis = 1000 * (audioBuffer.length / audioBuffer.sampleRate);

  const source = new AudioBufferSourceNode(oc);
  source.buffer = audioBuffer;

  const az = new AnalyserNode(oc, {
    fftSize: numberOfSamples * 2,
    smoothingTimeConstant,
    minDecibels,
    maxDecibels,
  });
  source.connect(az).connect(oc.destination);

  const msPerFrame = 1000 / fps;
  let currentFrame = 0;

  function process() {
    const frequencies = new Uint8Array(az.frequencyBinCount);
    az.getByteFrequencyData(frequencies);

    // const times = new number[](az.frequencyBinCount);
    // az.getByteTimeDomainData(times);

    frameFrequencies[currentFrame] = frequencies;

    const nextTime = (currentFrame + 1) * msPerFrame;

    if (nextTime < lengthInMillis) {
      currentFrame++;
      const nextTimeSeconds = (currentFrame * msPerFrame) / 1000;
      oc.suspend(nextTimeSeconds).then(process);
    }

    oc.resume();
  }

  oc.suspend(0).then(process);

  source.start(0);
  await oc.startRendering();

  return frameFrequencies;
}

const buttonsDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(buttonsDiv);

const initButton = document.createElement('button');
initButton.onclick = init;
initButton.innerHTML = 'Load audio'
buttonsDiv.appendChild(initButton);

const processButton = document.createElement('button');
processButton.disabled = true;
processButton.innerHTML = 'Process'
buttonsDiv.appendChild(processButton);

const resultElement = document.createElement('pre');
document.body.appendChild(resultElement)



async function init() {
  initButton.disabled = true;
  resultElement.innerText += 'Loading audio... ';

  const audioContext = new AudioContext();

  const arrayBuffer = await fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marcusstenbeck/da36a5fc2eeeba14ae9f984a580db1da/raw/84c53582d3936ac78625a31029022c8fdb734b2a/base64audio.txt').then(r => r.text()).then(fetch).then(r => r.arrayBuffer())
  
  resultElement.innerText += 'finished.';

  resultElement.innerText += '\nDecoding audio... ';
  const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
  resultElement.innerText += 'finished.';
  
  processButton.onclick = async () => {
    processButton.disabled = true;
    resultElement.innerText += '\nStart processing... ';
      const t0 = Date.now();
    
    await processFrequencyData(audioBuffer, {
      fps: 30,
      numberOfSamples: 2 ** 13,
      maxDecibels: -25,
      minDecibels: -70,
      smoothingTimeConstant: 0.2,
    });
    
    resultElement.innerText += `finished in ${Date.now() - t0} ms`;
    processButton.disabled = false;
  };
  
  processButton.disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is really a bug in Safari. I'm able to reproduce it by rendering an `OfflineAudioContext` without any nodes. As soon as I use `suspend()`/`resume()` every invocation takes a little longer.

I'm only speculating here but I think it's possible that there is some internal mechanism which tries to prevent the rapid back and forth between the audio thread and the main thread. It almost feels like one of those login forms which takes a bit longer to validate the password every time you try.

Anyway I think you can avoid using `suspend()`/`resume()` for your particular use case. It should be possible to create an `OfflineAudioContext` for each of the slices instead. In order to get the same effect you would only render the particular slice with each `OfflineAudioContext`.

```
const currentTime = 0;

while (currentTime < duration) {
    const offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext({
        length: LENGTH_OF_ONE_SLICE,
        sampleRate
    });
    const audioBufferSourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(
        offlineAudioContext,
        {
            buffer
        }
    );
    const analyserNode = new AnalyserNode(offlineAudioContext);

    audioBufferSourceNode.start(0, currentTime);

    audioBufferSourceNode
        .connect(analyserNode)
        .connect(offlineAudioContext.destination);
    
    await offlineAudioContext.startRendering();

    const frequencies = new Uint8Array(analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);

    analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(frequencies);

    // do something with the frequencies ...

    currentTime += LENGTH_OF_ONE_SLICE * sampleRate;
}
```

I think the only thing missing would be the smoothing since each of those slices will have it's own `AnalyserNode`.

Comment: This is a interesting approach, I'll come back when I've had time to try it out. Thanks!